# How to optimise github actions in a simple setup-lint-test-e2e-build scenario?

Tags: github, github-actions

If we were to use minimal resources, doing these steps would look something like:

setup --- checkout, install fixed versions via cache

then trigger in parallel 1 command to run:

- lint
- test
- e2e

all in parallel.

Unfortunately, with the current options I've found out there, the best scenario I can find is to have a separate workflow file for lint, test, e2e that are called by a main workflow and upon success build an artifact.

The issue with this is.

- checkout will run 3 times.
- install command will run 3 times.

Which can be mitigated with caching, but you're still looking at 10-15 seconds extra per job for those steps.

Is there a way to optimise this and still keep the reusable steps?

Even if I would keep everything in 1 giant file, I'd still define the lint, test, e2e steps as separate jobs and not as 1 single step part of a job.

Can we call a 'workflow' and run it in the same environment on the spot somehow?

Comment: If you could provide a minimal reproducible example (as a repo) that would be helpful to iterate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example calls checkout and caches the repo using the $ {{ github.run_id }} to prevent the cache conflicting with other runs. The cache is then used by the child workflows in place of checking out. e2e, test and lint will wait for the cache to be created and then all run in parallel.

Depending on your use case it may be excessive to create a new cache for each run_id, you can adjust this as you need. If speed is what you're after I'd also suggest only caching the files that you need for your child workflows, and not take everything like I've done in the example below.

```
name: main_caller
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
cache_checkout:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: my-checkout-${{ github.run_id }}
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/**/*

run_lint:
  needs: cache_checkout
  uses: ./.github/workflows/lint.yml

run_test:
  needs: cache_checkout
  uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yml
```

./.github/workflows/lint.yml example: (e2e and test will follow  this pattern)

```
name: lint
on: workflow_call
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get Cached Checkout
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: my-checkout-${{ github.run_id }}
      - name: Do linting things
        run: echo "I'm linting!"
```

Comment: @Petah is this what you're offering the bounty for? 

unfortunately I'm in a different stage of development and can't test this out right now, Petah is the one who has offered the bounty, happy to mark this as the right answer if Petah's satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

Edited as per comments - all `jobs` in GitHub run in parallel, but to have cleaner example you could use `matrix strategy`. To make it work you need it to depend on a 'setup' job that will install everything and create the artifacts (this is done using the `needs` keyword).

In the following example the `install` job would setup everything and then the `example` job, which uses matrix strategy, will run the lint/test/e2e flow in separate parallel jobs after it downloads the required artifacts.

```
jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Compile artifacts
      run: *install fixed versions/create artifacts*

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: my-artifact
        path: path/to/my_artifact


  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install
    strategy:
      matrix:
        action: [lint, test, e2e]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: my-artifact
        path: path/to/artifact

    - name: lint
      if:  ${{ matrix.lint }}
      run: echo "lint"

    - name: test
      if: ${{ matrix.test }}
      run: echo "test"
 
    - name: e2e
      if:  ${{ matrix.e2e }}
      run: echo "e2e"
```

It will create a workflow like this:

[image]

Comment: Jobs run in parallel by default, using a matrix isn't necessary to achieve this.